# Doctrine composite primary key as part of the primary key of another entity

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, composite-primary-key

I have specific situation where composite primary key of one entity is part of the primary key of another entity. This is case of specialization, but it doesn't matter now.

I use Doctrine to generate entities from database, but Doctrine doesn't support composite foreign key as primary key:

```
It is not possible to map entity 'XXXXX' with a composite primary key as part of the primary key of another entity 'YYYYYY#id_xxxxx'
```

Does anyone know solution for this situation? It can be Doctrine solution or editing model and database structure.

UPDATE 1

```
CREATE TABLE `amandman` (
  `iddokumenta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datumdostavljanjaskupstini` date NOT NULL,
  `tekst` text,
  `datumizmene` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `izmenjenitekst` text,
  `iddokumentapredlogazakona` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datumdostavljanjaskupstinipredlogazakona` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iddokumenta`,`datumdostavljanjaskupstini`),
  KEY `iddokumentapredlogazakona_idx`           (`iddokumentapredlogazakona`,`datumdostavljanjaskupstinipredlogazakona`),
  CONSTRAINT `iddokumenta45` FOREIGN KEY (`iddokumenta`, `datumdostavljanjaskupstini`)     REFERENCES `dokument` (`iddokument`, `datumdostavljanjaskupstini`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON     UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `iddokumentapredlogazakona` FOREIGN KEY (`iddokumentapredlogazakona`, `datumdostavljanjaskupstinipredlogazakona`) REFERENCES `predlogzakona` (`iddokumenta`, `datumdostavljanjaskupstini`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is one of entities from database that can't be generated by Doctrine.

Comment: What do you mean by mean by "composite"? Did you just string two keys together or did you create a primary key spanning two columns?

Comment: Can you copy your Entities in the question, please?

Comment: I am sorry for late response. By composite I mean primary key spanning of two columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are running into this problem because your composite foreign key is another table's composite primary key. This is not a good development practice, which is why it is simply not supported by Doctrine, and I strongly doubt that it ever will be.

**Solution 1 (preferred):**

Add a single, auto-increment primary key to `EstablecimientosSec`. You can then link to that `EstablecimientosSec.id` instead.

**Solution 2:**

If changing the database structure is absolutely not possible, do not map the relationship. Instead, you can fetch the related `EstablecimientosSec` entities in a separate query using the composite primary key. It's not a prefect solution, but it works under these constraints. Tip: avoid querying the related objects as part of a loop.

Comment: I just came about the same problem. Solution 1 is not possible for me. What do you mean exactly with solution 2? And how to do it?

Comment: @craphunter Don't link the entities together using ManyToOne so that Doctrine won't complain. If you need to fetch related records from the other table, create a separate query and use `where table2.id = ?`. Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

The foreign key ever is a primary key in other table and why it's not a good practice?.
The solution is remove the foreign key relation from the database, after add it manually. Well if you are using cascade update or similar it's necesary or you can control the update/delete with code and not with relation of tables

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).